# Upgrading Vulnerable jars inside another jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar created its name is x.jar. inside that, I have bundled jackson-databind-2.10.1, httpclient-4.5.4. My client ran some security scans and found some vlunerabilities in jackson-databind-2.10.1, httpclient-4.5.4.  I need to send a new x.jar to the client with jackson-databind-2.11.3, httpclient-4.5.13(upgraded version). what should be the approach instead of another build?

I have some limitations to doing a new build. So I approached by replacing the META-INF\maven\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind folder inside x.jar using winRAR tool.

Answer (score 0):

Very, very few programmers have your problem, so there is no industry standard solution. The ordinary thing you do is:

- Change the versions in your `pom.xml` file, *OR* use your standard dependency checking infra to update them all.
- With the updated pom file, rerun all the tests. (`mvn test`)
- re-assemble, probably with `mvn assembly:single` or whatnot.

If you can't do those steps you're off the beaten path so to speak, and whatever you do is going to be half-baked, and likely isn't going to work (so, do your testing manually, I guess? There's a reason the above is how its commonly done, testing by hand is error prone and takes ages).

Some versions of java require that the META-INF and MANIFEST.MF entries are at the top, along with a few other requirements, in that sense a `jar` file isn't quite like a `zip` file, and thus using arbitrary zip-capable tools such as winrar may also cause issues to occur. Probably not though, and you *are* going to test this before blindly handing it to your client and souring that relationship even further, right?

If that was a problem, unjar it all with:

```
mkdir unjarred
cd unjarred
jar tvf ../thejar.jar
```

then make your changes and re-jar with:

```
jar cmvf ../thenewjar.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF *
```